# Compare two tables look for gaps, append them in new table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

This is related to MS Access 2007. I'm in bit of a pickle and anyone who can solve this for me I will be greatly indebted to.

I have two tables: Actual and Schedule. My job is to compare these two tables, look for gaps, and fill them in a new table (append). Important point: tbnum corresponds to timeband. It's something I came up with to identify gaps easily. I have created these sample tables:

http://i39.tinypic.com/2mhesxs.jpg

There are 2 scenarios:

1. JFKATL: there is a match in Actual table, so bring the original record for JFKATL from Schedule as well as from Actual for the missing JFKATL record into NewTable
2. ORDSLC: there is no match in Actual table, but there is an apparent "gap" in timeband. So extend the timeband for the unmatched record and paste it in NewTable

**Edit:** Sorry, there was a small issue i noticed in the original image. Posted new one.

Comment: In "NewTable", the row highlighted in green isn't in either of the other tables. Where is it supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your problem completely or correctly, but it appears that an [UNION operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140015%28v=office.10%29.aspx) will work for you. UNION will combine the unique records between two queries and merge them into one recordset.  UNION ALL will include duplicates.

```
SELECT c1, c2
FROM table1

UNION

SELECT c1, c2
FROM table2;
```